# PHP/ARRAY/HTML TABLE -- How come this repeats the same thing across the whole <td>?

Tags: html, arrays, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Im trying to turn an array of friends names: $friends['name'] from the Facebook Graph API into a table with 4 columns across with one persons name in each box.

The problem:

I have it making a table and putting peoples names in the cells of the table, however, it repeats each persons name across all 4  in a row instead of putting a unique name in each box. However the next row starts with a new name.

I would greatly appreaciate anybody who can help point out where Ive gone wrong and help me correct it:

```
    <? 
    $friends_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/".$user_id."/friends?access_token=".$access_token;
    $friends_json = file_get_contents($friends_url);
    $friends_data = json_decode($friends_json, true);       
    $friends_total = count($friends_data['data']);
    $cols = 4;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $friends_total; $i++) 
    {
            $friends = $friends_data['data'][$i];
            echo "<tr>"; 
                for ($c=0; $c<$cols; $c++) 
                {
                $n = $i+$c;
                    if ( $n < $friends_total) 
                    {
                        echo "<td>".$friends['name']."</td>"; 
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo "<td></td>";
                    }
                } 
            echo "</tr>"; 
        $i += ($c-1); 
    } 
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're looping 4 times for each friend and your loop counter for 'columns' is inside that loop, try something more like this:

```
$cols = 4;
$current_col = 0;

    echo "<tr>"; 
    foreach ($friends_data['data'] as $friend)
    {
      echo "<td>".$friend['name']."</td>"; 
      if (($current_col++)%$cols == 0){
        echo "</tr><tr>";
      }
    }
   while (($current_col++)%$col !=0){
   echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
   }
   echo "</tr>";
```

This loops through all the friends, keeping a counter of how many have been printed. After 4 (/or whatever $cols is set to) it spits out a new row
When the friends are all printed out, it starts a new loop to fill in the end of the last row with empty cells, then ends the row

Comment: Ahh thank you, I knew it was something like that, I just couldnt figure out what was in the wrong place.